# Chrome debugger simulate memory limit

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, chrome-debugging

I am trying to debug out of memory issues when my JS code runs on an old ipad

Is there a way to set a simulated memory limit in Chrome dev tools so that I will get Out of memory exceptions etc when it is breached ?